# converting a SAS Macro to python with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sas, sas-macro

I'm converting a program of SAS code into a python equivalent. One section that i'm struggling with is how to convert a macro program in SAS when the variables used within the macro are used to create a dataset. for example:

Say my data has a column called type, and that takes either value of ‘tree’ or ‘bush’, I want to split my data in two, and then process the same functions on both and create separate output tables for both. In SAS this is quite simple. I write macros which are effectively functions that take my arguments and drop them into the code, making them unique datasets.

```
%macro program(type);
data portfolio_&type.;
set portfolio (where=(type=&type.));
run;


Proc freq data=Portfolio_&type.;
Tables var1 var2/out=summary_&type.;
Run;


%mend;
%program(Tree);
%program(bush);
```

The & allows me to drop my text into the dataset name but I can’t do this with a def function type statement in python because I can’t drop the argument into my data frame name